# How to recognize the box using ARCore?

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, arcore

I want to recognize a certain box (like tissue box) using ARCore, ViroCore (or OpenGL) and OpenCV, and display the width, depth, and height of the box.

1. Use OpenCV to detect the edge through the sobel filter.
2. Use OpenCV to recognize the edge detected box and acquire coordinates.
3. Use ARCore to calculate width, depth, height from acquired coordinates.
4. Use ARCore and ViroCore (or OpenGL) to display the calculated length.

I can not imagine how to implement No. 2.

Is it possible to recognize the box automatically?
If it is possible, how should it be implemented?

> [Development environment]
>
> > Android Studio 3.0.1(Not Unity!)
> >     Kotlin(or Java)
> >     Samsung Galaxy S8+

Comment: Just to clarify, is your intent to put bounding boxes around the contours (edges) you detect? Just so that I can tailor  my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that you didn't do any research. ARCore is not a image recognition tool. So it has nothing to do with your problem. You need to use an image/object recognition tool like OpenCV. 
About your questions. Yes, it is possible. How to do it? I suggest to read examples, OpenCV has a big library of ready examples like car shape recognition. To recognize a box you can use an edge tracking algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It's not abundantly clear what your intent is, so let me know if this is not what you're looking for. It seems like this tutorial on [putting bounding boxes around contours](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d0c/tutorial_bounding_rects_circles.html) would contain an example of how to fetch the coordinates of the edges.